# I get an exception when writing to Excel cell

Tags: c#, excel, exception, visual-studio-2008

I have a listview and I am trying to save the data in the listview to an Excel workbook. The exception occurs on the `ws.Cells[row,col]` line. Here is my code:

```cs
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...
Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
xl.Visible = false;
Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)xl.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;

for (int row = 0; row < listView1.Items.Count; row++)
{
    ListViewItem item = listView1.Items[row];

    for (int col = 0; col < item.SubItems.Count; col++)
    {
        ws.Cells[row,col] = item.SubItems[col].Text.ToString(); // exception here
        //ws.Cells[row,col] = "Test"; // I've tried this too
    }
 }
```

The exception is:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC)

I've done some research on the error code, but I've only been able to find issues with people trying to save the file. I'm not at the point of saving the file and I am getting the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Cells` indexer is one-based not zero-based (so `A1` is `[1, 1]`)

```
for (int row = 1; row <= listView1.Items.Count; row++)
...
   for (int col = 1; col <= item.SubItems.Count; col++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel cells are 1-base indexing, try:

```
ws.Cells[row + 1,col + 1] = item.SubItems[col].Text.ToString();
```